# .htaccess rewrite multiple urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need help with this rewrite in .htaccess file.
So this what I have now ans this works but when I try to add a new RewriteRule nothing happens.
I the url that I want to be rewrite is index.php?page=$1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

So when I do it like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

The page doesn't have any css when i do it like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*_)$ index.php?page=$1
```

The page has css but i still get index.php?page=pagetitle. But the profile page does give me /*username*.

Comment: You have to add more details to the question. it is unclear what you ask. "Nothing happens" is nothing that helps. What rule do you want to add, how do you do it? What do you want to happen? Please use the `edit` button above and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Your are asking the server to redirect every URL to two different pages, it cannot work the server cannot just guess what page to load.

What you need is either a /profile/username rule or a /page/pagetitle rule.
IE something like:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: is there no other way to achieve the same? I don't mind to redo the .htaccess

Comment: Your example matches the exact same pattern as in the original question because `^(.*)$` will match `^profile/(.*)$` as well. Check out http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rules are based on regular expressions and therefore need to be as specific as possible so the server can determine exactly which url to use - for example how can you tell if http://example.com/something is a page or a profile? Using a prefix such as "user", "profile", etc on your URLs means that http://example.com/profile/something can be redirected as as a username with a default redirect for everything else. To accomplish this you need to make the more specific pattern match first (users) and utilized the `[L]` directive to indicate that following rules should not be processed. I usually use a negative character class for URLs to match anything *except* a forward slash - `[^/]*`.

```
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# Set the base directory
RewriteBase /
# Don't process if this is an actual file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Does this url start with /profile and then followed with additional characters?
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
# Assume everything else is a page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Test at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ (note that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` aren't supported for testing).

**Profile**

```
input url
http://www.example.com/profile/something

output url
http://www.example.com/profile.php

debugging info
1 RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]  
    This rule was met, the new url is http://www.example.com/profile.php
    The tests are stopped because the L in your RewriteRule options
2 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Page**

```
input url
http://www.example.com/something

output url
http://www.example.com/index.php

debugging info
1 RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]  
2 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
    This rule was met, the new url is http://www.example.com/index.php
    The tests are stopped because the L in your RewriteRule options
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I don't know where it goes wrong but when I use your rules it also won't work.